# Re-Subscribe contacts who have unsubscribed on contact creation as a result of Journey using salesforce data entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql, automation, subscriber

I have a journey with a SF data as entry source, this journey captures new contacts created in SF using SFMC connector. On Salesforce, when a contact is created, the initial state of emailoptout is TRUE which result in subscriber unsubscribes from ALL Contacts.
When I search for any contacts (who entered the above journey) i get the following "This subscriber is unsubscribed from the enterprise level and cannot be activated from this business unit." i also noticed that the unsubscribe date is equal to creation date.

I have managed to pull those unsubscribers using the following SQL Query

```
SELECT sub.SubscriberKey,sub.Status, sfob.HasOptedOutOfEmail,sub.DateJoined,sub.DateUnsubscribed
FROM ent._Subscribers sub
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT con.Id, con.Email, con.HasOptedOutOfEmail FROM ent.Contact_Salesforce con) sfob 
ON sub.SubscriberKey = sfob.Id
WHERE 
sub.Status = 'unsubscribed' AND 
sfob.HasOptedOutOfEmail = 'FALSE' AND 
sub.DateJoined = sub.DateUnsubscribed
```

How can I update the all subscribers with this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the subscriber status in the All subscribers list manually (one time),

1. Export the result data extension. Make sure to include the email address field and all other required fields.
2. Add a column named Status to your file. Populate this field with the word 'Active' for each contact.
3. Import that file to the All subscribers list.
4. Make sure to select an 'update' option.
5. Finish the field mapping.
6. and complete the process of import.

Once the import is complete, you will see the status of those contact will be updated to 'Active'.

NOTE: This import should be done from the Parent Business Unit.

If you want to make this process recurring, you can create an automation to do this.

You can follow the steps mentioned in the article below:

[Update All Subscriber List in Marketing Cloud](https://salesforceweek.ly/2020/10/27/update-all-subscriber-list-in-marketing-cloud/)

Please NOTE that, Updating status in the all subscriber list does not update the 'EmailOptOut' field value in the SF.
If the status is active in the SFMC and 'EmailOptOut = False' for the contact, he will not receive an email.

Hope this helps.